# Replace libsane 1.0.27 with 1.0.25

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate

I want to replace my current libsane version with

libsane_1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1_amd64.deb

to see if I can resolve the longstanding problem of my scanner not working.

I do not which of the following I need to uninstall.

[image]

Comment: You must replace both `libsane1` and `libsane-common` with two silmiarly-named packages of the version you prefer. Using a different package name will break SANE functionality. This is a problem: The package name (and corresponding dependency chain) changed between 16.04 and 18.04, so 16.04 packages CANNOT be interchangably used on 18.04 and newer systems without extensive work. If you simply want to try the older version, a much faster and easier way is to burn a 16.04 LiveUSB and try that.